Mount Google Drive on Google Colab with write access
How can I mount my Google Drive on Google Colab with write access?
That's because I'm receiving an error when my AI model tries to update a file on Google Drive:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/Deep3DFaceRecon_pytorch/test.py", line 72, in <module>
    opt = TestOptions().parse()  # get test options
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/content/Deep3DFaceRecon_pytorch/options/base_options.py", line 167, in parse
    self.print_options(opt)
  File "/content/Deep3DFaceRecon_pytorch/options/base_options.py", line 115, in print_options
    with open(file_name, 'wt') as opt_file:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: './checkpoints/facerecon_20230425/test_opt.txt'

By the way, I have already copied my folders from Google Drive to Google Colab:
!git clone https://github.com/sicxu/Deep3DFaceRecon_pytorch.git
%cd Deep3DFaceRecon_pytorch

...

!mkdir checkpoints
!cp -r ../drive/MyDrive/Deep3D/facerecon_20230425 checkpoints/

...

UPDATE
On Google Colab, just trying to create a file inside the mounted Google Drive throws an error:
!touch ./checkpoints/facerecon_20230425/test_opt.txt

Log:
touch: cannot touch './checkpoints/facerecon_20230425/test_opt.txt': Read-only file system


you don't appear to be writing to drive that error message doesn't match the code you have shown us './checkpoints/facerecon_20230425/test_opt.txt'   checkpoints isnt on drive.

@LindaLawton-DaImTo I'm copying facerecon_20230425 from Google Drive to my local folder. I'm not sure, but looks like the copying process is just creating a symbolic link or something like that...

Then your statement sounds backwards Google Drive on Google Colab with write access  you want to mount a google drive folder on colab with write access.  mounting drive does have write access automatically drive.mount('/content/drive')
but again cp copy from one place to another in your case from drive onto your colab instance not leaving it on drive.

first you could check /full/path/to/file to make sure you write in correct place. Second: as for me you try to write on local system (in Colab), not on Google Drive - so it is not problem with Google Drive. Third: you may have system with write access but you can still set some files or folders as read-only - using command chmod (change mode)

Shared folder
Deep copy
The Google Drive folder that I mounted on Google Colab, with which I had permission problems, was shared with me by someone else. So, I made a deep copy of the shared folder by copying its content to a new folder of my own:
!cp ../drive/MyDrive/Deep3D/facerecon_20230425--original/epoch_20.pth ../drive/MyDrive/Deep3D/facerecon_20230425/
!cp ../drive/MyDrive/Deep3D/facerecon_20230425--original/loss_log.txt ../drive/MyDrive/Deep3D/facerecon_20230425/
!cp ../drive/MyDrive/Deep3D/facerecon_20230425--original/train_opt.txt ../drive/MyDrive/Deep3D/facerecon_20230425/

After deep copying, the permission errors were resolved.
This post helped me: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138917/154722
